# PHP related- getting SQL Server 2005 to cooperate with Windows Server 2003

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, windows-server-2003

I realize the software I'm asking about are outdated to say the least, however it's due to the constraints placed upon this experiment. This is not a homework assignment, merely an experiment to test sql injection across several operating systems and configurations.

I'm trying to find a way to set up a MS SQL server on a Windows Server 2003 machine, and it is being difficult. I finally got all of it set up, I can run phpinfo() on the local host with success, but when running my query after submitting a username and password through the htm file, I get this error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client installed, since 2012 is not compatible with 2003. I've tried and it just results in errors during install. If anyone has a solution or something I might have overlooked, that would be perfect.

For some additional insight, here is my php file that is run. Mind the comments, it was formerly a MySQL php script:

```
<?php

echo "<center> <img src=\"bookstore.jpg\"><br /> "; 
echo "<font color=green size=6> Database Query Results </font>";
$Id = $_POST["Id"];
$pass =  $_POST["pass"];
#$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fname"]);
#$age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["age"]);
$db_host = '.\SQLExpress';
$db_user = 'SCADATEST';
$db_pwd = '';
$database = 'bookorders';
$table = 'Customers';
// Connect to the database server
//$con = mssql_connect('localhost', 'SCADATEST', '');
//$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $db_user, "PWD" => $db_pwd, "Database"=>$database);
//$connection = mssql_connect('localhost', 'SCADATEST', '');
//$con = sqlsrv_connect($db_host, $connectionInfo);
//if (!$con)
//  {
//#  die('Could not connect: ' . $age . '   '.mysql_error());
//  die('Could not connect: ' . '   ' . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
//  }

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"$database");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $db_host, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


// Open to the database
//mysql_select_db("bookorders") or die(mysql_error());

//Create query string
$QueryStr = 'SELECT * FROM Customers where Username=\'' . $Id . '\' and Pwd=\'' . $pass . '\';'; 
#$QueryStr = 'SELECT * FROM Customers; SELECT * FROM Orders; -- and Pwd='; 

//$QueryStr= "SELECT * FROM Customers where Username='' OR 1=1; -- ' and Pwd='fsd';"

//echo $QueryStr ;
//echo "<br />";

$queries = preg_split("/;+(?=([^'|^\\\']*['|\\\'][^'\^\\\']*['|\\\'])*[^'\^\\\']*[^'|^\\\']$)/",$QueryStr);
#$queries = split('[/;]',$QueryStr);

// Select all records from the "Individual" table
foreach ($queries as $query){
    if (strlen(trim($query)) > 0){ 
                $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<HR><P><table border=2><tr>";
                //first print the column names as headers
        for ($i=0; $i < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $i++){
                    $field_info = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
            echo "<th>{$field_info->name}</th>";
        } 
            echo "</tr>";
             // Loop thru each record (using the PHP $row variable),

         while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){

                //now print the data                
        $c=0;
        echo "<tr>";
        while ($c < sqlsrv_num_fields($result)){
            echo "<td>{$row[$c]}</td>";
                        $c++;
               } //end of inner while
                 echo "</tr>";
             }//end of outer while
         echo "</table> <P> <HR>";
     } //end of if

echo "<br /><br /> ";
} //end of for each
echo "<a href=\"index.html\"> Return to Home </a> ";
echo "<hr><font color=red size=1> Copyright 2013. Guillermo Francia, III-Jacksonville State <hr></center>";

sqlsrv_close($con);

?>
```

Any help anyone might have for getting this to function would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the old mssql api, or just go plain odbc. sqqlsrv() was not arround in 2003. which extension is php using? If it needs 2012 native client I would suspect a VC9 .dll.
try downgrading to VC6

--edit I just checked the manual. you cant use sqlsrv below win server 2008SP2.
You'll have to use one of the older extensions (mssql or plain old odbc).
Start here for mssql
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php
you may have to downgrade your PHP.
for ODBC create a windows DSN: control panel->data sources (i think, it's been a while)
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is to use FreeTDS drivers in PHP (php_dblib.dll). [Moodle](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP) has well written docs how to set it up.